# SparkStreaming either running 2 times the same command or mail sending 2 times same mail

Tags: apache-spark, jakarta-mail, spark-streaming

My spark application sends two mails when I send just 1 string to my Kafka Topic. Here is the interested part of code:

```
    JavaDStream<String> lines = kafkaStream.map ( [returns the 2nd value of the tuple];
    lines.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
    [... some stuff ...]

    JavaRDD<String[]> flagAddedRDD = associatedToPersonRDD.map(new Function<String[],String[]>(){

                @Override
                public String[] call(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
                    String[] s = new String[arg0.length+1];
                    System.arraycopy(arg0, 0, s, 0, arg0.length);
                    int a = FilePrinter.getAge(arg0[CSVExampleDevice.LENGTH+People.BIRTH_DATE]);
                    int p = Integer.parseInt(arg0[CSVExampleDevice.PULSE]);
                    if(
                        ((p<=45 || p>=185)&&(a<=12 || a>=70))
                            || 
                        (p>=190 || p<=40)){
                        s[arg0.length]="1";
                        Mailer.sendMail(mailTo, arg0);
                        }
                    else 
                        s[arg0.length]="0";
                    return s;
                }

            });`
```

I cannot understand if the mail sends two emails, because the transformation after this one is a save on file and this only return 1 line. The mailer.sendMail:

```
public static void sendMail(String whoTo, String[] whoIsDying){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mail.***.com"); //edited
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("***my-email***")); //edited
        for (String string : whoTo.split(",")) 
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress(string));
        message.setSubject(whoIsDying[PersonClass.TIMESTAMP]);
        message.setText("trial");
        System.out.println("INFO: sent mail");
        Transport.send(message);    
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explicitly mention the place where mail sending logic resides? Is it in transformation, e.g. map, or output operation, e.g. foreachRDD?

Comment: Most likely your Function with the call method is being called by the map method more than once.  Certainly you can trace this with a debugger or println calls, right?

Comment: @TarasMatyashovskyy The function is called in a Map transformation, but I cannot understand why it would be passed 2 times. The map function is inside a foreachRDD, because not all the lines should be sent via mail.
Does this mean that all of what it gets is being processed twice?

Comment: @BillShannon I have put a print line and indeed I now see two times the "mail sent". Why is it being called twice if the line I feed it is one, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because I called two actions at the end of the transformation:

```
FilePrinter.saveAssociatedAsCSV(associatedSavePath, unifiedAssociatedStringRDD.collect()); //first action

                JavaRDD<String[]> enrichedWithWeatherRDD = flagAddedRDD.map(new Function<String[],String[]>(){ [some more stuff] });

                JavaRDD<String> unifiedEnrichedStringRDD = enrichedWithWeatherRDD.map(unifyArrayIntoString);

                FilePrinter.saveEnrichedAsCSV(enrichedSavePath, unifiedEnrichedStringRDD.collect()); //second action
```

and thus the whole transformation is called again and the mailer part is above both of these actions.